# Clear input value in template

Tags: angular

I have the following input. On icon click i want to clear the value. How is it possible to clear the value without using two way binding? I get:

> vendor.js:31300 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property value of [object Object] which has only a getter

[image]

```
 <input matInput 
            ngModel
            #searchPattern="ngModel"
            name="search"
            required
            >

            <button mat-button 
            *ngIf="searchPattern.value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
            (click)="searchPattern.value=''"
            >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to manually set the value to an empty string, you could use the [`resetForm()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#resetform) function.

Try the following

```html
<button 
  mat-button 
  *ngIf="searchPattern.value" 
  matSuffix 
  mat-icon-button 
  aria-label="Clear"
  (click)="searchPattern.resetForm()"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input #searchPattern placeholder="Search" />
<button (click)="searchPattern.value = '';">Close</button>
```